# Selenium IDE: verifyTextPresent inside concrete element

Tags: selenium

I would like to verify that concrete text for example "hello" exists inside concrete element that has class "world". So basically I would like verifyTextPresent to return true for such document:

```
<div class="world">
   Hello
</div>
```

but return false for

```
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

I have experimented a little, for example something like

```
verifyTextPresent
target: css=.world
value: hello
```

but of course this did not work - the "hello" is normally inside "target". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `verifyText` (select command by right-clicking on the specified element), like:

```
verifyText | css=h2.space | Your Answer
```

Comment: thanks I will check this and then I will come back to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

if you use `Verifytextpresent` command, in this command you do not write target value use only value and in value field write 'pattern'

```
Command: verifyTextPresent
target:
value: hello
```

If you use `verifytext` command then you needed both target and value field

```
verifyText | css=h2.space | Your Answer
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use Verifytextpresent or asserttextpresent command, through this command you do not write target value use only value and in value field write 'pattern' which pattern do you want to verify through selenium ide

```
 Command: verifyTextPresent
 target:
 value: hello
```

If you use verifytext or asserttest command then you needed both target and value field in selenium ide